# Once SPF is correctly setup is it normal for spoofed email to go to spam folder or should Gmail deleted them?

Tags: email, spam, spf

In the spam folder of Gmail can be found illegitimate spam emails *apparently* sent from my own domain email address but from an origin not allowed by SPF. The domain is on G Suite emails. SPF is allegedly correctly setup as "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all". What is the expected behavior of Gmail in that case. Should it delete those emails so they do not even reach the spam folder or should they appear in spam.

Comment: Side note: with `~all`, you're telling Gmail "I'm not sure about my SPF record, let everything through". A pass may *reduce* the spam score, but a fail will not increase it. You want `-all` for it to penalize failing emails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the ease of messing up an SPF record, Gmail appears to consider a failing SPF check as a major factor for the spam score of an email, but it's *possible* for it to still wind up in the inbox.

To my knowledge, Gmail will *not* just silently delete an email by default.

If you're in a Google Apps install, there may be rules the administrator put in place. [This doc](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en) indicates a DMARC record may be used to have SPF-fail email deleted.

Comment: Thanks for taking time on a Sunday to help a stranger! The info is exactly what I needed. Yes the domain is on G Suite emails by Google.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Gmail does not silently delete emails. However in some cases Gmail will refuse to receive an email in the first place. To the receiver that will look the same as if it was deleted. The sender will eventually receive an error message about failed delivery.